# How to get values of the gridview hidden fields in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am getting an error on accessing gridview hidden field Ids while trying to save the gridview row details. What i want to do is to save the all gridview rows back to database. I am bit confused on accessing the value of the row ids. Please help me to overcome this problem.

```
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
                        DataKeyNames="ServiceID" Font-Names="Segoe UI Symbol" Font-Size="11pt" RowStyle-BackColor="#A1DCF2"
                        ShowFooter="true" Width="670px">
                        ForeColor="White" />
                        <PagerStyle CssClass="cssPager" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                        <Columns>
                            <%--ServiceID--%>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ServiceID" ItemStyle-Width="100px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblServiceID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ServiceId")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="100px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>

                            <%-- ServiceName --%>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Service" ItemStyle-Width="200px">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblService" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ServiceName")%>'></asp:Label>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <ItemStyle Width="300px" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                         </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
```

### Code Behind

//Save TestDetails

```
   foreach (GridViewRow rw in GridView1.Rows)
    {
            var n = new TestDetail
            {
                PriceListId = txtPriceList.text,
                ServiceId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[rw.RowIndex].Value),
                Price = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPrice.Text.ToString()),
            };

            using (var context = new DiagEntities())
            {
                context.TestDetail.Add(n);
                context.SaveChanges();

            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks...Now its working correctly...rectified code is given above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `DataKeys`:

```
// Get the index of the current row.
int index = rw.RowIndex;

// Based on the index of the row 
// get the DataKey value and convert it to an int
ServiceId = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value);
```

Comment: Thanks Christos! I implement the same now it is inserting more rows then intended.

Comment: @You welcome dude. You will choose which row will be inserted. However, as I can infer from your code, you loop through all the rows of the gridview, when you click on save details. Hence all the rows of the gridview will be inserted.